# C programming getc and while loop behaviour

Tags: c

I am trying to read a file using FILE *fp, fgets

```
 while( (ch=getc(fp)) != '\n' ){
    printf("%d\n",ch);
 }
```

The peculiar thing is, this code prints also the newline. Isn't the while loop saying to print if its not "\n" being detected? How can I do it such that it doesn't print the "\n". thanks

Comment: printf("%d",ch);  << without \n?

Comment: Are you sure it is getting a newline? It can also return `EOF` when reaching end of file or an error occurs. If you're on Windows, you might also have to accomodate for end of line being carriage return _and_ newline `\r\n`.

Comment: hi, sorry for the confusion. it is indeed \r\n. so the correct way is to check for '\n' and '\r'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one is reading from a file to do string processing (a text file), insure the file is opened in *text* mode.

Files opened in text mode on systems that use something other than `"\n"` to indicate the end-of-line like `"\r\n"` or `"\n\r"` or `"\r` will transform that into  `"\n"`.  Other processing may happen too concerning Byte-order-marks (BOM or end-of-file characters (^Z).

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("fielanme", "r");
```

OTOH, if open wants to open the file in binary, be prepared for variant line endings.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("fielanme", "rb");
```